# R - replicating IF() logic command from Excel to R

Tags: r

```
date        A    B   C
11/24/2016   0  -1  -1
11/23/2016  -1  -1  -1
11/22/2016   0  -1  -1
11/21/2016   0  -1  -1
11/18/2016  -1  -1  -1
11/17/2016  -1  -1  -1
11/16/2016  -1  -1  -1
11/15/2016  -1  -1  -1
11/14/2016  -1  -1  -1
11/11/2016  -1  -1  -1
11/10/2016   0  -1  0
11/9/2016    0  -1  0
```

The excel command (assuming data begins in row2) for the `C` is `=IF(A2=-1, -1, IF(AND(B2=-1,C3=-1),-1,0))`. So essentially, if column A is -1, then column C will also be -1. Otherwise, we will check if `B2=-1` and if the row below us in C is `-1`. In Excel, I was able to do this by simply copy/pasting the formula and the column C would automatically update itself. I don't think this is quite as simple in R.

In R, I have values for col `A` and `B`, and I would like to use these columns to create `C` like how I did via Excel. However, I've been stuck thinking about how to do this for quite some time. This is because 'C' depends on 'A', and if that fails it depends on 'B' and the lagged values of itself. Help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: I have something in mind that could possibly work.

```
for (i in 1:length(dat[,1])){

         dat[i,3] <- ifelse(dat[i,1]==-1, -1, 0)

       }
```

After running the first loop, I get:

```
  A  B V3
1   0 -1  0
2  -1 -1 -1
3   0 -1  0
4   0 -1  0
5  -1 -1 -1
6  -1 -1 -1
7  -1 -1 -1
8  -1 -1 -1
9  -1 -1 -1
10 -1 -1 -1
11  0 -1  0
12  0 -1  0
```

Now for the second condition:

```
for (i in 2:length(dat[,1])){

         dat[i-1,3] <- ifelse(dat[i-1,2]==-1&dat[i,3]==-1, -1, dat[i,3])

       }
```

For the second condition, I'm hoping that the `for()` will check the row before it and iteratively fill in `-1`s as long as there was a `-1` in the row before the current one in C and a `-1` one in the current row in B. However, this ends up returning:

```
    A  B V3
1   0 -1 -1
2  -1 -1  0
3   0 -1  0
4   0 -1 -1
5  -1 -1 -1
6  -1 -1 -1
7  -1 -1 -1
8  -1 -1 -1
9  -1 -1 -1
10 -1 -1  0
11  0 -1  0
12  0 -1  0
```

I need `row2` to stay as -1, so that `row3` can get filled as -1.

Comment: So you already have values for column `C` in place?

Comment: @Ronak Shah Sorry! Should have clarified. I have values for `A` and `B` in R, and I want to use those to create `C` like how I did in Excel. Will edit my post!

Comment: `dplyr::case_when` handles that pretty literally: `library(dplyr); df %>% mutate(C = case_when(A == -1 ~ -1, B == -1 & lead(C) == -1 ~ -1, TRUE ~ 0))` Otherwise you could use nested `ifelse` calls, but that gets messy.

Comment: @alistaire Thanks, would this work if `C` hasn't been generated yet?

Comment: Ah, no. So you're using values from the first condition from the next row for the second? Couldn't you just check when `A3=-1` directly? In that case, wouldn't the third row be 0?

Comment: @alistaire I'm using conditions from both 'B' and 'A', and the lagged value of 'C' to create 'C'. In a sense, my first condition is to check if `A2=-1`. If that fails, then I examine the case if `B2=-1` and if the lagged `C3=-1`. This was relatively simple in Excel because I could copy/paste the formula down the column and have `C` update itself, but I was wondering if there was a way in R to replicate this.

Comment: @alistaire Ideally, for the second condition, I want the program to continue with `-1`s as long as there's been a previous value of `-1`s in the lagged row in `C` conditional on that there's a `-1` in B. I apologize if this sounds incredibly convoluted. I'm also wondering if there's a pattern that I'm not seeing that would let me easily do this.

Comment: Ok, so for `C2`, at most you need the value of `A2`, `B2` and `C3`?

Comment: @sebastian-c Yup, edited my post to reflect my current train of thought. I'm thinking a `for()` function that iterates through the rows will work, but I'm having trouble implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that because you're drawing from the following value of what you're calculating, you need to start calculating from the bottom, as the values there could cascade all the way to the top. `Reduce` with `right = TRUE` and `accumulate = TRUE` can create the logic:

```r
df$C <- sapply(
    Reduce(
        function(x, y){
            if (x[[1]] == -1) { -1 } else if (x[[2]] == -1 & y[[1]] == -1) { -1 } else { 0 }
        }, 
        Map(c, df$A, df$B), right = TRUE, accumulate = TRUE), 
    `[`, 1)

df
#>          date  A  B  C
#> 1  11/24/2016  0 -1 -1
#> 2  11/23/2016 -1 -1 -1
#> 3  11/22/2016  0 -1 -1
#> 4  11/21/2016  0 -1 -1
#> 5  11/18/2016 -1 -1 -1
#> 6  11/17/2016 -1 -1 -1
#> 7  11/16/2016 -1 -1 -1
#> 8  11/15/2016 -1 -1 -1
#> 9  11/14/2016 -1 -1 -1
#> 10 11/11/2016 -1 -1 -1
#> 11 11/10/2016  0 -1  0
#> 12  11/9/2016  0 -1  0
```

Since it has to run an iteration for every row, it won't be terribly fast, but will be fine for 1k rows.

All that said, the logic here is suspect, and you should carefully consider in context whether what you're calculating makes any sense.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware that `Reduce` could do this. I'm having a little difficulty rewriting this for my original data, which is a list of data.frames. If my original sample data was one of  many of my data.frames (df[[1]] to return all columns, and df[[1]][,3] to retrieve column C), how would I implement the above code?

Comment: You can map the whole thing across a list inside of `lapply`, or if the data.frame are all similar anyway, bind them into one big data.frame with an ID column for which element they came from (`dplyr::bind_rows` with its `.id` parameter set makes this easy) and apply it by group. You could also look at `purrr`, which has a lot of utilities for working with lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'ifelse' function in R:

```
x<-data.set.name
y<-ifelse(x$A==-1,-1,ifelse(x$B==-1 & X$C==-1,-1,0))
```

This should do it.

Comment: You need to get the value of `C` from the next row, though.

Comment: Hi, I think it might be `lead` or `lag` C? Also, the problem I'm having is that `C` hasn't actually been generated in R. In Excel, I was able to copy/paste the formula and have column `C` automatically update itself. I'm not quite sure how this would work in R.

Comment: @alistaire Yup. And to complicate matters, I have to somehow generate `C` in R.